# PointerRealease event on a label delay

Tags: codenameone

I am having an issue with my program,
I use codenameone for mobile application and here is my problem:

I have a lable like this:

```
Label l=new Label("my label");
```

Then i bind and action on it like this:

```
l.addPointerReleasedListener((e)->{
                                new MyNewFormr().show();
                            });
```

Now my problem is that, new form takes a delay before showing, how can i make new form show right away without any delay??

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using Label for that, unless you have a special requirement, which is unlikely in most cases. Use Button instead of Label and it's also as simple... see below:

```
Button btn = new Button("my label");
btn.setUIID("Label"); //To make the button look like a Label if required. Just remember to style the pressed state
btn.addActionListener(e->new MyNewFormr().show());
```

Comment: FYI you should accept Diamond's or Jeremys answer to reward them for the help. Use the check box to the left to pick one of the answers and ideally upvote them...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build the form before your label will be pressed and agree with Diamond post, so I would say :

```
 MyNewFormr form = new MyNewFormr();
 Button b = new Button("my button");  
 b.addActionListener((e)->{
       form.show();
 });
```